# How to redirect users when they access the website's view page source?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am using the code below to redirect users that did not come from google. It can also prevent direct access to that link without going to google. But why does when I view the page source of my domain ( view-source:https://owndomain.com/NMkrujlS ), it does not redirect to example.com?  isn't viewing page source a direct access to my domain? How can I fix this?
Thanks

My code:

```js
var ref = document.referrer;
if (ref.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?google\.com(\/|$)/i)) {
    // do nothing
} else {
   // redirect
   window.location.replace("https://example.com" + window.location.pathname);
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! In view source mode, no javascript code is executed, so it's perfectly normal that you are not redirected. It's an intended behavior. However, consider the possibility that there may be people using other search engines or being refered to your website via link, and somethings the `document.referer` variable is empty due to rpivacy parameters.

Comment: Thanks but I saw a website that redirects users when they click view source I tried to copy it but i dont know how. Maybe they uses htaccess redirect or something.

Comment: @Winie Can you provide a link to said page or some other authoritative document which leads you to believe that this is even possible or what scenario in which this would be expected behavior? Simply “[viewing] source” should most certainly not be able to cause a redirect (it would likely constitute some sort of bug/flaw in the browser itself). When viewing the raw source, as the commenter above mentioned, the code itself shouldn’t be executed - that would defeat the purpose of viewing the source altogether, no?

Comment: Would you like to share the website you observed the redirection with? I suppose it should be a server redirection, because when content arrives at the browser and the browser is set to use the `view-source` handler, it just displays the raw content for what's received, without executing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you linked in the comments of your original question uses a header-based redirect, which is why when you point your instance of Chrome to `view-source:rshrt.com/getlink/YCy`, it redirects you to the target page. This is in line with how browsers are expected to handle header-based redirects. This fact is confirmed if you open your developer tools' Network tab and inspect the requests that your browser sends to the target site, which show the `rshrt.com` page redirecting with a `301 Moved Permanently` status code (along with the respective `Location` header, which points to the target page):

[image]

---

In your own example, you're performing a redirect using JavaScript. This JavaScript isn't executed/interpreted by the browser when using `view-source`. As such, the redirection never happens.

If you'd like this to function moreso like the site you've given as an example, you'll have to configure these redirection rules at a server level to correctly return a `301` or `302` status code (as well as the appropriate `Location` header), instead of on the client level using JavaScript. How *specifically* you would accomplish that is entirely dependent on the stack your server runs, and is arguably outside the current scope of the question as you've posed it.

Comment: Again, the scope of this question isn't really conducive to providing an answer, especially not based on code you've left in a comment (that's not really what comments are for). I would recommend you generate a new question on this topic, but be forewarned that it will likely be closed as a duplicate as "how to perform a redirect in PHP" is a topic that has been covered extensively on this very site in the past. In any case, "*it didn't work*" is not a very particularly helpful problem statement. You should include all pertinent debugging details (error messages, expected vs. actual behavior).

Comment: I successfully redirected it using PHP. But i dont know the equivalent of this javascript to PHP. " + window.location.pathname  " because I am new to PHP, sorry. I'll try to create new queestion. thanks again